# Is this code multi-thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, static-methods

```
    private static Map<Integer, String> map = null;

    public static String getString(int parameter){

        if(map == null){

            map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            //map gets filled here...

        }

        return map.get(parameter);
    }
```

Is that code unsafe as multithreading goes?

Comment: What language is this?  Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, it's definitely not safe.  If the contents of the map are not based on the parameter in getString(), then you would be better served by initializing the map as a static initializer as follows:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> MAP = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

static {
  // Populate map here
}
```

The above code gets called once, when the class is loaded. It's completely thread safe (although future modification to the map are not).
Are you trying to lazy load it for performance reasons?  If so, this is much safer:

```
private static Map<Integer, String> map = null;

public synchronized static String getString(int parameter){

    if(map == null){

        map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        //map gets filled here...

    }

    return map.get(parameter);
}
```

Using the [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) keyword will make sure that only a single thread can execute the method at any one time, and that changes to the map reference are always propagated.

If you're asking this question, I recommend reading "Java Concurrency in Practice".

Comment: +1 for JCIP, kind of a beast to get through, but it's the kind of book I'm glad to have read.

Comment: Agreed Paul, after several years I still don't comprehend the entire thing. Well worth it though...

Answer (score 2):

**Race condition? Possibly.**

If `map` is `null`, and two threads check `if (map == null)` at the same time, each would allocate a separate map. This may or may not be a problem, depending mainly on whether `map` is invariant. Even if the map is invariant, the cost of populating the map may also become an issue.

**Memory leak? No.**

The garbage collector will do its job correctly regardless of the race condition.

Comment: Well... memory leak: Maybe.  While this looks like a managed language like Java (=no), the OP has not actually specified that.

Comment: Actually the more likely race condition failure scenario is the one I describe in my answer (presuming the time cost of populating the map is greater than the cost of allocating an empty one).

Answer (score 1):

You do run the risk of initializing `map` twice in a multi-threaded scenario.

In a managed language, the garbage collector will eventually dispose of the no-longer-referenced instance.  In an unmanaged language, you will never free the memory allocated for the overwritten map.

Either way, initialization should be properly protected so that multiple threads do not run initialization code at the same time.

One reason: The first thread could be in the middle of initializing the HashMap, while a second thread comes a long, sees that `map` is not null, and merrily tries to use the partially-initialized data structure.

Comment: dramatically changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is unsafe in multithreading case due to race condition.

But do you really need the lazy initialization for the map? If the map is going to be used anyway, seems you could just do eager initialization for it..

Answer (score 1):

The above code isn't thread-safe, as others have mentioned, your map can be initialized twice.  You may be tempted to try and fix the above code by adding some synchronization, this is known as "double checked locking", [Here is an article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) that describes the problems with this approach, as well as some potential fixes.

The simplest solution is to make the field a static field in a separate class:

```
class HelperSingleton {
  static Helper singleton = new Helper();
 }
```

it can also be fixed using the volatile keyword, as described in Bill Pugh's article.

Answer (score 0):

No, this code is not safe for use by multiple threads.

There is a race condition in the initialization of the map. For example, multiple threads could initialize the map simultaneously and clobber each others' writes.

There are no memory barriers to ensure that modifications made by a thread are visible to other threads. For example, each thread could use its own copy of the map because they never "see" the values written by another thread.

There is no atomicity to ensure that invariants are preserved as the map is accessed concurrently. For example, a thread that's performing a `get()` operation could get into an infinite loop because another thread rehashed the buckets during a simultaneous `put()` operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 6, use ConcurrentHashMap

[ConcurrentHashMap JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)